# Loading cck fields from nodes of a content type

Tags: entities

I have created 4 nodes by a content type called insert_item using CCK; now I am trying to load all CCK fields into a template of a new node where I would use the CCK field value of the insert_item content type.

What I have written is the following code:

```
$nodes = array();
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'insert_item'");
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $nodes[] = node_load($row->nid);
  print $nodes;
}
```

What I got is the following:

> ArrayArrayArrayArray

I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `print $nodes` to `print_r($nodes)` and also move it to the outside of your `while` loop.

Your code should look like this:

```
$nodes = array();
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'insert_item'");
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $nodes[] = node_load($row->nid);
}
print_r($nodes);
//If you use Devel, uncomment this next line and comment out print_r above
//dpm($nodes);
```

This will give you an easy to read value.

Another option is to use the [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, and instead of using `print_r` you can use `dpm()` which uses Krumo to pretty print the contents of your array.  There are some basic instructions for that `dpm()` [here](http://drupal.org/node/174575) and [here](https://ratatosk.backpackit.com/pub/1836982-debugging-drupal).

*Information on `print_r` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).*

> If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows
>   keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.

Comment: Ok thanks now it works:-D , i'd like to print for example all fields called fields_email: [field_email] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 546546546546@4532132.com ) )  i've thought to print in this way print $field_email[0]['value']; but it dosn't work

Comment: I think you'll be looking at doing $nodes[0]->field_email[0]['value'] or somesuch.

Comment: yes and it works great!

Comment: Awesome - glad to be of help.